# Change python path of imported module

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, module, sys.path

I have these files on my computer:

```
some/random/path/config.py
my/path/defined/here/file1.py
my/other/path/here/file2.py
```

Then, I have:

```
#File: config.py
import sys
path1="my/path/defined/here/"
sys.path.append(path1)
path2="my/other/path/here"
sys.path.append(path2)

import file1
```

and,

```
#File: file1.py
import file2
file2.runFunction()
```

The path "my/path/defined/here/" is defined in config.py, but I would like to somehow add that same path to file1.py so that I can import file2.py in file1.py.  I would like to be able to do this without having the exact path in file1.py as I will have multiple config.py py files.

Comment: What are the problems/errors you ran into?

Comment: I just edited it, file1.py and file2.py are in different directories, so when I try to import file2.py from file1.py, it can't find the file.

Comment: Try adding `import sys; sys.path.append("my/other/path/here")` in file1.py and see whether it is resolved.

Comment: That would work, however, I am trying to do this without including that line in file1.py since I would like to use the same file1.py will be used for multiple config.py files.

So Ideally I would like to change the path for file1.py from config.py.